# How can I profile a shell script?

Tags: shell-script, time, profiling

I have several programs that I'm executing in a shell script:

```
./myprogram1
./myprogram2
...
```

I know that I can profile each individual program by editing the source code, but I wanted to know if there was a way I could measure the total time executed by profiling the script itself.  Is there a timer program that I can use for this purpose?  If so, how precise is its measurement?

Comment: maybe this be helpful profiling - How to profile a bash shell script? - Stack Overflow -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014823/how-to-profile-a-bash-shell-script

Comment: Have a look at this question about performance profiling tools for shell scripts: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4336035/247696

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Start by using time as per Jon Lin's suggestion:

```
$ time ls test
test

real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.002s
sys     0m0.002s
```

You don't say what unix your scripts are running on but strace on linux, truss on Solaris/AIX, and I think tusc on hp-ux let you learn a lot about what a process is doing. I like strace's -c option to get a nice summary:

```
]$ strace -c ls
test
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 89.19    0.000998         998         1           execve
 10.81    0.000121         121         1           write
  0.00    0.000000           0        12           read
  0.00    0.000000           0        93        79 open
  0.00    0.000000           0        16           close
  0.00    0.000000           0         2         1 access
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           brk
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           ioctl
  0.00    0.000000           0         4           munmap
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           uname
  0.00    0.000000           0         6           mprotect
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           rt_sigaction
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           rt_sigprocmask
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getrlimit
  0.00    0.000000           0        30           mmap2
  0.00    0.000000           0         8         7 stat64
  0.00    0.000000           0        13           fstat64
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           getdents64
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           fcntl64
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           futex
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           set_thread_area
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           set_tid_address
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           set_robust_list
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           socket
  0.00    0.000000           0         1         1 connect
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.001119                   205        88 total
```

Do also note that attaching these tracing type programs can slow the program down somewhat.

Comment: Actually, I'm using Redhat mostly, but I'm starting to use Debian (ubuntu) more often these days too.

Comment: `strace` might profile a binary *in* the shell script, but you can

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [`time` command](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?time). You can use it to measure the time it takes to execute along with some other useful info like where the time is being spent.

Answer (score 4):

Since I've ended up here at least twice now, I implemented a solution:

https://github.com/walles/shellprof

It runs your script, transparently clocks all lines printed, and at the end prints a top 10 list of the lines that were on screen the longest:

```
~/s/shellprof (master|✔) $ ./shellprof ./testcase.sh
quick
slow
quick

Timings for printed lines:
1.01s: slow
0.00s: <<<PROGRAM START>>>
0.00s: quick
0.00s: quick
~/s/shellprof (master|✔) $
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not exactly profiling, but you can trace your script as it runs. Put `set -xv` before the section you want to trace and `set +xv` after the section. `set -x` enables xtrace, which will show every line that executes. `set -v` enables verbose mode, which will also show lines that may have an effect, but are not executed, such as variable assignment.

You can also timestamp your trace. You need a terminal emulator that can timestamp every line; the only one I know of is [RealTerm](http://realterm.sourceforge.net/), which is a Windows program, but it will work with Wine. You might also be able to use [`grabserial`](http://elinux.org/Grabserial), although I've not tried it except with real serial ports. You can find out what serial device your shell is using by running `ps -p $$` (if it doesn't, use `man` to find out how to include the TTY column in your `ps` output).

Also, see [Performance profiling tools for shell scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336035/performance-profiling-tools-for-shell-scripts) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

### `time` for several iterations

Profiling by running the same command multiple times

```
time (for ((n=0;n<10;n++)); do echo "scale=1000; 4*a(1)" | bc -l; done)
```

Where `echo "scale=1000; 4*a(1)" | bc -l` computes pi and `time (...)` ensures that the `for` loop runs as a single command.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manually add some logging statements at key points in your script, you could include the following function in your bash script.

Note that it takes some time (~ 50 ms) to shell out to python to get the current timestamp, so using this will increase run times slightly, but will help you easily log time between commands in your script.

```
function traceTick(){
  local CURR_TIME=$(python -c "import time; print(int(time.time()*1000))")
  if [ -z "$LAST_TIME" ]
  then
    START_TIME=$CURR_TIME
    LAST_TIME=$CURR_TIME
  fi

  local DELTA=$(($CURR_TIME - $LAST_TIME))
  local TOTAL_DELTA=$(($CURR_TIME - $START_TIME))
  LAST_TIME=$CURR_TIME

  printf "elapsed(ms):%-6s delta(ms):%-6s %s\n" $TOTAL_DELTA $DELTA "$1"
}
```

##### Using it in a script like so

```
traceTick 'starting'
...
traceTick 'did something'
...
traceTick 'more stuff'
```

##### will output something like the following

```
elapsed(ms):0      delta(ms):0      starting
elapsed(ms):2597   delta(ms):2597   did something
elapsed(ms):6560   delta(ms):3963   more stuff
```

Comment: `date "+%s%3N"` will give you milliseconds without having to spin up Python.

Comment: Thanks - that seems to work fine!